# Android Search View in fragment not taking input?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, searchview, android-toolbar

My app structure is like this:
Main activity - Checks whether it's the first run and open signup activity , else open default activity.

default activity - has a navigation drawer and 4 fragments.

I have a search view, in a fragment, not in the toolbar but in layout.
Doesn't even display the keyboard on touch!
What am I doing wrong?

**layout.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchContent1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ingredientSearch"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

       

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/plateButton"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plate"
            android:contentDescription="@string/container" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchContent2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Searchable.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Hint">

</searchable>
```

**Manifest**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smart_mat.dev.main" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.smart_mat.dev.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.smart_mat.dev.main.AlwaysActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.smart_mat.dev.main.SearchActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.smart_mat.dev.userprofiledata.UserGoal">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

                        
        <activity android:name="com.smart_mat.dev.login.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.smart_mat.dev.login.SignUp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show me how you declared the searchview in oncreateoptionmenu();.

Comment: @SurenderKumar `searchView = (SearchView)dataSearch.findViewById(R.id.ingredientSearch);` But it's in `onCreateView` because the searchView is not in the actionBar.

Comment: can you post searchview code ?

Comment: @SurenderKumar I didn't code for SearchView because it doesn't even take input. I started recreating what I have done so far and the moment I added navigation drawer the issue began again. Now I know the issue comes with navigation drawer. No idea why though.

Comment: @SurenderKumar `drawerLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);` This line is what causes the problem. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment search view should be called like this

SearchView searchView = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchView1);

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.d("query", query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.d("genres 1", newText);
            fillAdapter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```